# Set Image Width & height to 50% of its original in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I'm a Flutter developer and I don't have experience in native Android.

I need the splash screen's image to be 50% of its size.

Let's say the image resolution is 120x120px and I want it to show 60x60px.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="?android:colorBackground" />

    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with API>23 and although there is no width and height parameters for bitmap, you can set bitmap size using gravity and item width/height.

```
 <item
        android:width="60dp"
        android:height="60dp">
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal|fill_vertical"
            android:src="@mipmap/launch_image" />
    </item>
```

Comment: Thanks but I actually want to show 50% of the size, it should not be hard coded